# Are school fee receipts good enough as proof of ties for a Canadian Visitor Visa with Family?

Tags: visas, canada, family, proof-of-ties

I'm applying for a Canadian Visiting Visa with my family. Can I submit the most recent school fees receipt of my kids as part of the documents to prove that we will not remain in Canada after the stipulated period we are applying for?

Comment: Why do you think you can’t?

Comment: You can submit pretty much anything you like if you think it will help your case. Proof that you have paid for schooling in advance will probably help your case, and certainly not hurt it.

Comment: I think where you're a citizen would play a big role in this.

Answer (score 1):

What the government is looking for in the application process is evidence that you plan to return and not try and overstay in Canada.

Any and all evidence that you think might help (Eg school fees indicate your kids are at school in your home country), a letter from your work, maybe a lease agreement - can help.  They may ignore some of it, but more evidence is usually better than too little.